# How to put cell that for loop is in, in a message box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Vba and want to be able to put the cell the for loop is in into a msgbox.
This is my code:

```vb
For Each Cell In Range("C5:C11")
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then
         MsgBox "Please input a number for cell " & Cell & " that isn't 0."
    End If
```

I'm not sure exactly what to put to get the code to output the cell the for loop is currently on in the msgbox.

Comment: A hint: try to inform yourself first about `InputBox` and/or `Application.InputBox` and edit your question accordingly if there arises an issue :-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may be after this:

```
For Each Cell In Range("C5:C11")
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number for cell " & Cell.Address & " that isn't 0."
    End If
Next
```